# Regex - match multiple words that starts with

Tags: regex

I have the current regex

```
/(?=.*?Joe)(?=.*?Doe).*/i
```

It returns true when I match it to Joe Doe, but how can I prevent it from matching names that don't start with "Joe" or "Doe"

i.e. Joe McDoe should return false.

Comment: `\s` is the symbol for whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

```
/(?=.*?\bJoe)(?=.*?\bDoe)/
```

`\b` is a word break.  A space counts as does the beginning of the string.

Comment: +1 Word boundaries are a superior choice to matching whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
/(?=.*?\wJoe)(?=.*?\wDoe).*/i
```

Comment: Not sure if interpreted OP correct. But I thought by `prevent it from matching names that don't start with "Joe" or "Doe"` OP meant a string like `'BanJoe ShaDoe'`